# Is it necessary to unadvise an IConnectionPointImpl before it gets destroyed?

Tags: c++, com

As for the title, I have a com event and some class has called the `Advise` on it. Is it necessary for the `Unadvise` function to be called before the com object generating the event gets destroyed?

Comment: That looks like an invalid assumption to me.  You are assuming that the object *can* be destroyed, even though the client code has a reference to it.  Which it needs to call Unadvise again.  That's a ref count bug in the client code, you can't fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is necessary. Before you unadvise it, the connection point holds a sink interface pointer and prevents from its release. It is not going to release it before it receives `Unadvise` request. Not doing Unadvise you are going to have it alive forever causing a memory leak like condition, and sink will keep receiving events possibly causing other issues.

If you are releasing the event source and this causes source destruction, then yes it could possibly release all sink pointers. However it is not going to happen if someone else is also holding a reference to this object. So it is very easy to end up with circular references, and it's pretty hard to nail them down when they start creating a leak.

Circular references are typical in case of connection points. You hold point's interface for unadvise purposes, and connection point holds your sink interface back. Unadvise is how you typically initiate graceful termination of this reference between COM objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's not strictly necessary according to the spec, but it is a good idea.

If you don't, what *should* happen is when the object goes away the connection point should release your event sink interface anyway. However if the connection point is badly implemented they may forget to do that, then your sink object will never be destroyed.

If you call `Unadvise`, that's one less mistake for other people to make.

It's also one less mistake for you to make: If someone else is holding on to an object reference, then it won't go away when you release it, so you will continue to get events, which you probably won't expect to happen, so may well cause further errors.